# Database is not created while release Erlang application

Tags: erlang, rebar

I created a Erlang application, a small calendar_server. Which insert events, retrieve them and also edit and delete the events. It works correctly when run on the prompt(using erl). I inserted events(birthdays, meetings etc), then the database(**Mnesia.nonode@nohost**) is created on the directory. And it possible to retrieve the events. But when created the same application using rebar/rebar3, no database is created. I really like to know what the problem i have faced, or what mistake i did.

The reltool.config and calendarApp.app.src are given below..

**reltool.config**

```
{sys, [
   {lib_dirs, ["../apps"]},
   {erts, [{mod_cond, derived}, {app_file, strip}]},
   {app_file, strip},
   {rel, "calendarApp", "1",
    [
     kernel,
     stdlib,
     sasl,
     mnesia,
     calendarApp
    ]},
   {rel, "start_clean", "",
    [
     kernel,
     stdlib
    ]},
   {boot_rel, "calendarApp"},
   {profile, embedded},
   {incl_cond, exclude},
   {excl_archive_filters, [".*"]}, %% Do not archive built libs
   {excl_sys_filters, ["^bin/.*", "^erts.*/bin/(dialyzer|typer)",
                       "^erts.*/(doc|info|include|lib|man|src)"]},
   {excl_app_filters, ["\.gitignore"]},
   {app, sasl,   [{incl_cond, include}]},
   {app, stdlib, [{incl_cond, include}]},
   {app, kernel, [{incl_cond, include}]},
   {app, mnesia, [{incl_cond, include}]},
   {app, calendarApp, [{incl_cond, include}]}
  ]}.

  {target_dir, "calendarApp"}.

  {overlay, [
          {mkdir, "log/sasl"},
          {copy, "files/erl", "\{\{erts_vsn\}\}/bin/erl"},
          {copy, "files/nodetool", "\{\{erts_vsn\}\}/bin/nodetool"},
          {copy, "files/calendarApp", "bin/calendarApp"},
           {copy, "files/calendarApp.cmd", "bin/calendarApp.cmd"},
           {copy, "files/start_erl.cmd", "bin/start_erl.cmd"},
           {copy, "files/install_upgrade.escript",     "bin/install_upgrade.escript"},
           {copy, "files/sys.config", "releases/\{\{rel_vsn\}\}/sys.config"},
           {copy, "files/vm.args", "releases/\{\{rel_vsn\}\}/vm.args"}
      ]}.
```

**calendarApp.app.src**

```
{application, calendarApp,
 [
  {description, ""},
  {vsn, "1"},
  {registered, []},
  {applications, [
              kernel,
              stdlib,
              mnesia
             ]},
  {mod, { calendarApp_app, []}},
  {env, []}
 ]}.
```

If anyone know why the database is not created, please help me to find my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

For creating disc-based Mnesia you can use `mnesia:create_schema/1` function (which I think you did somewhere in your code). This function requires Mnesia to be **stopped**.

In your `reltool.config` you specified `mnesia` application before `calendarApp` application which is where you probably created mnesia disc-based schema. It means that mnesia was started before creating its schema, so the schema cannot be created.

If you change the order of `mnesia` and `calendarApp` under the key of `rel` in your `reltool.config` file, everything should be correct.

```
{sys, [
   {lib_dirs, ["../apps"]},
   {erts, [{mod_cond, derived}, {app_file, strip}]},
   {app_file, strip},
   {rel, "calendarApp", "1",
    [
     kernel,
     stdlib,
     sasl,
     calendarApp,
     mnesia
    ]},
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you, let me try it and get back to you soon. Once again thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I started myApp (dumperl_sync) first:

```
{relx, [{release, { dumperl_sync, "0.1.0" },
     [dumperl_sync,
      sasl,
      mnesia
     ]},
     ...
 }.
```

Then, in application behaviour:

```
start(_Application, _Type) ->
    application:set_env(mnesia, dir,"/path/to/Mnesia.node"),
    mnesia:create_schema([node()])
    ...
end.
```

Then, in gen_server behaviour inside handle_info:

```
handle_info(_, State) ->
    mnesia:start(),
    mnesia:create_table(dates,
        [
            {disc_only_copies, [node()]},
            {attributes,record_info(fields, dates)} 
        ]
    )
    ....
 {noreply, State}.
```

dates is a record:

```
-record(dates,{}).
```

Everything should be correct!